# Include file in plugin file

Tags: plugin-development, include

I have a working plugin with many functions in it. I want to break the plugin into several file. I removed some functions and place it in a file called activate.php k7Course.php. Then in the file k7Couses.php i include as below:

```
/*
Plugin Name: k7 Course Management
Plugin URI: http://yourdomain.com/
Description: A plugin to manage k7 Courses Display
Version: 1.0
Author: Noor
Author URI: http://yourdomain.com
License: GPL
*/

require_once('activate.php');
```

The problem is that the code in activate.php in being included but as raw text because i see all the content of activate.php in the admin menu. Also the function are not being executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though your include file activate.php does not have the opening/closing php tags.  Be sure to open activate.php and ensure it has the `<?php` at the beginning of the file, and the  `?>` at the end.

Comment: you were, I just took the functions and paste it there, stupid error :(